# sqrt function causing " 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type" error

Tags: c++

I am working in C++, making a pretty simple function that is supposed to calculate the standard deviation of a given number entered by the user. But when I try to use the `sqrt` function with my variable `mean`, there is an error I get when attempting to compile my program:

> 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type

Below is my code, as well as a picture of the error message.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tgmath.h>
#include "stddev.h" //this is just a seperate header file that I have going with my program

using namespace std;

void stats (float *data, int n){

    float mean = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        mean += data[i];
    }

    mean = mean / n;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) { //subtracting the mean from the number and squaring the result.
        data[i] = data[i] - mean;
        data[i] = data[i] * data[i];
    }

    mean = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        mean += data[i];
    }

    mean = mean / n;

    float stdDeviation = sqrt(mean); //Here is where I get the error

    cout << "\t Your Standard Deviation is : " << stdDeviation << endl;
}
```

[image]

Comment: After I changed `#include "stddev.h"` to `#include <iostream>`, your program compiled without error. But using `<tgmath.h>` in C++ might be problematic.

Comment: `<tgmath.h>` in C++ is completely unnecessary. Just go for `<cmath>` and `std::sqrt`. Plus, you also need `<iostream>`.

Comment: @DeiDei: Probably `<iostream>` is included by `"stddev.h"`, which the OP hasn't shown us.

Comment: A piece of the puzzle: tgmath.h implements `sqrt` as a macro.  This means that that one line gets expanded to something much more complicated.  What you may be seeing is an artifact of using C99 functionality (tgmath) in C++.  However the exact reason why this particular error shows up won't be easy to figure out without looking at your computer's particular headers.

Comment: `<tgmath.h>` is a C header that defines macros to work around C's lack of function overloading. An implementation of it is likely to use some weird stuff that might not work with C++. As @DeiDei says, just use `<cmath>` and the overloaded `std::sqrt` function.

Comment: Why is your code not indented?

Comment: I removed the <tgmath.h> and put <cmath> instead and it compiles just fine. Thanks so much, I was very confused

Comment: On my computer it is but because I'm on this like virtual desktop for my University I had to email the code to my email and it removed my indentations for some reason

Comment: @JulioReyes I have re-added indentation to your code for you. Next time, please add it yourself before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `<tgmath.h>` (or `<ctgmath>`) is deprecated in C++.

It's supposed to still work -- `<tgmath.h>` is meant to be exactly equivalent to including `<cmath>` and `<complex>` -- so you are looking at a compiler/library bug. But perhaps this is something that the vendors are not really interested in putting time into fixing since it is deprecated.

Things should go more smoothly to use  `#include <cmath>` instead of `#include <tgmath.h>`.